# Is Using Packages in Types Good Convention?

Tags: java, types, package

Is it good convention, in Java, to use something like

```
 java.net.URL myUrl = new URL(...);
```

or should I try my best to use an import and

```
 import java.net.URL;
 URL myUrl = new URL(...);
```

Comment: It's just a matter of style. Fully qualified names remove ambiguity and make it easier to find where the referenced class is, but also clutter up the code with overly long names (one of Java's fortes).

Comment: It depends.  Normally I would use `import` as it greatly simplifies the code (and the amount I need to type), however, if I wanted to highlight that the Object is derived from another package/library I might consider using the fully qualified name or if I was using two Objects with the same name (like `Document`) for example

Comment: For something like Object, you'd have to qualify it as otherwise it would clash with `java.lang.Object`, which is imported automatically.

Comment: I see. So what I'm hearing is it's a decision decided solely based on preference?

Comment: My understanding is that using `import` is the more conventional way to do that, while using fully qualified names is somewhat less common.

Comment: I just wish the syntax was like Python where you could import + rename (`from foo.bar import baz as MySpiffyBaz`)

Comment: I'm thinking the downvoter has downvoted it because of common sense (which I was brand new to Java at the time.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a matter of style, mostly. Your IDE may be able to convert from one to other by use of a code formatter.

The exception is the use of two or more classes or interfaces with the same name but from different packages in one compilation unit (i.e. class). Then you have to use the fully qualified name in at least one case. Importing two single types with the same name from different packages will result in a compile time error.

Of course you can find the details in the JLS:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-7.html - on packages and imports

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.5.1 - single imports and conflicts

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html - on names

That said I don't see any additional value of using the fully qualified name when not needed but it does clutter the code.

So the typical convention is to use imports; exponents of using the fully qualified name all the time are rare.

Comment: Thanks!
I've been using a package name when my class is linking to another class with the same name, but I use imports whenever possible... it gets on my nerves to have

"my.long.package.name.running.out.of.Ideas i = new my.long.package.name.running.out.of.Ideas(my.long.package.name.running.out.of.Ideas.randomIdea());"

or something.